# profilers for programming languages

Tags: java, profiler

I am working on Profilers.
Can anyone list out the advantages of using profilers.

How Java profilers work? What technologies to use? Please if you have some good articles then forward me the links.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both JProfiler and YourKit.  The advantage of using a profiler is that you can find what parts of your code really cost time by measuring, rather than theorizing.

Both work by using a JVM agent and JVMTI (the Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface):
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html